# can I make this a one-liner in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I often am doing something like this:

```
t={};
t.args={};
```

and then assigning variables like `t.args.id=12`. Can I make the above a one-liner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about something like:

```
var t = { args: { id: 12 } };
```

This will be accessible with:

```
t.args.id;
```

If you don't want to specify the inner-attributes of `t.args` during initialization (i.e. - `id`), you could just as easily go with `t = { args: {} }` as well. Then use `t.args.id = 12` will still work just-the-same.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var t = { args: {} };
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work but it isn't necessarily most readable approach:

`(t={}).args={}`